# Baking the normal map from high poly mesh ends up weird. I have no more ideas how does this work

Tags: normals, baking, normal-map

Well I just heard that for creating game asset I should learn how to bake normal map on the low poly model from it's high detail version. I tried to follow tutorials but no matter what my results end up poorly, like this:
[image: left is low poly with baked normal map, on the right it's high poly version.]

Low poly mesh is uv-unwrapped, both have smooth shading too and I'm in cycles render. Now I've tried everything. Incerasing ray distance does nothing and creates seams, using cage mesh removes seams but still details look bad or won't even exist. Changing margin size seems to do nothing at all.

So my normal maps seem to work only, with smoothered edges, adding holes or some shapes sticking out of the mesh, do nothing at all or just look poor. I have no idea what's going on so either I'm missing something or Blender hates me and won't allow to bake a normal map.

Edit: Additional details

[image]

Left mesh is low poly with normal map, right one is high poly, and that's the normal map I got. By "it looks poor" I mean, that the top part, doesn't even show on the normal map and these small faces around the mesh that are going slightly inside, are missing top and bottom part from the high poly version (right mesh)

Comment: in what way does it look poor? Are these 2 objects the low-poly ones?

Comment: Hello :). Please add your normal map result and bake settings. It works just fine for me.

Comment: Is the problem that it looks too extruded? Have you tried decreasing the normal map strength when reconnecting?

Comment: @JachymMichal done.